# Is it possible to enable the ability to run backwards in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I would really like to know if you can run backwards in Minecraft?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In Vanilla Minecraft, you can't.

There is however, a mod that does this: [Better Sprinting](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1285563-better-sprinting-570-000-dls-enhanced-sprinting). This mod allows you to use keybinds for sprinting instead of using the default 'double-tap forward' feature. It also allows you to toggle an option to turn on sprinting in all directions, which is exactly what you want - plus it allows you to sprint sideways as well!

[image: Better Sprinting Keybind Menu]

Have a look at the video below to see it in action:

Comment: There is a key bind for sprint... Default Left Ctrl

Comment: @ModDL - True, but it IS the primary point of the mod hence why I mentioned it - the sprinting sideways/backwards is a secondary feature, but it will do what the OP wants to do :)